Error al inicializar la session
¡Hola equipo!
Estoy enfrentando un problema relacionado con el manejo de sesiones en PHP. Aunque en el archivo de login los datos de la sesión se envían correctamente y parecen estar configurados, al llegar al archivo index.php, estos datos no están disponibles o no se cargan como esperaba.
He verificado el código y la lógica en ambos archivos, pero aún no he logrado resolver este inconveniente.
Para facilitar el diagnóstico y una mejor comprensión del problema, comparto a continuación el código relevante de ambos archivos. Agradecería mucho su ayuda o cualquier sugerencia para solucionar este comportamiento.
¡Gracias de antemano!
Login.php
<?php
session_start();
include("./Conexion_bd.php");
$longitud_clave = 64; // Puedes ajustar esta longitud según tus necesidades
// Generar bytes aleatorios
$bytes_aleatorios = random_bytes($longitud_clave);
// Convertir los bytes en una cadena hexadecimal
$clave_hexadecimal = bin2hex($bytes_aleatorios);
// La clave hexadecimal puede contener solo números y letras (en minúsculas)
// Si deseas letras en mayúsculas, puedes usar strtoupper() en la cadena resultante
$clave_final = $clave_hexadecimal;
// Construir el enlace con la clave aleatoria
$link = "../sidebar/index.php?key=" . $clave_final;
// Obtener las credenciales enviadas desde el formulario
$nombreUsuario = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
$contrasenaUser = $_POST['password'] ?? '';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.1.2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Preparar la consulta SQL de forma segura utilizando parámetros
$sql = "SELECT u.*, r.* FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.rol WHERE user = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

// Verificar si la preparación de la consulta falló
if ($stmt === false) {
    // Si la preparación falla, muestra un mensaje de error
    echo "Error en la preparación de la consulta SQL: " . $mysqli->error;
} else {
    // Bind de parámetros (s para string)
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $nombreUsuario);
    // Ejecutar la consulta
    $stmt->execute();
    // Obtener el resultado
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    // Verificar si se encontró el usuario
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        // Verificar la contraseña
        if (password_verify($contrasenaUser, $row["password"])) {
            $_SESSION['identificacion2'] = $row;
            $_SESSION['logeado'] = true;
            $_SESSION['prueba'] = "Hola Mundo";
            header("Location: $link");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "<script>
                Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Credenciales de acceso incorrectas',
                  text: 'Por favor, intente nuevamente',
                  icon: 'error'
                }).then(() => {
                  window.location.href = '../Vista/login.php';
                });
              </script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Credenciales de acceso incorrectas',
              text: 'Por favor, intente nuevamente',
              icon: 'error'
            }).then(() => {
              window.location.href = '../Vista/login.php';
            });
          </script>";
    }
    // Cerrar la declaración
    $stmt->close();
}
// Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
$mysqli->close();
// Enviar la salida almacenada al navegador
?>
</body>
</html>

index.php
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['prueba']; 
if (isset($_SESSION['identificacion2'])) {
    // Obtener el ID del usuario de la sesión
    $user_id = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['id']; // Verifica si 'id' está en la sesión
    $nombre_completo = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['nombre_completo'];
    $pSistemas = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pSistemas'];
    $pLogistica = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pLogistica'];
    $pAcceso = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pAcceso'];
    $pAmbiental = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pAmbiental'];
    $pCalidad = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pCalidad'];
    $pComercial = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pComercial'];
    $pProduccion = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pProduccion'];
    $pMantenimiento = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pMantenimiento'];
    $pCSistemas = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pCSistemas'];
    $pInventario = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pInventario'];
    $pDespachos = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['pDespachos'];
    $usuario = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['user'];
    $usuario_soft = $_SESSION['identificacion2']['user_softland'];
}
include("../Controlador/Conexion_bd.php");
require("../Controlador/session.php");
// Consulta SQL para obtener los datos del usuario
$sql = "SELECT u.foto, u.nombre_completo, u.cedula, u.email, r.roles FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.rol WHERE u.id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
// Verificar si la consulta fue preparada correctamente
if ($stmt === false) {
    die("Error al preparar la consulta: " . $mysqli->error);
}
// Vincular los parámetros
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id); // Asegúrate de que 'user_id' esté correctamente definido
// Ejecutar la consulta
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
// Verificar si se obtuvieron resultados
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Obtener los datos del primer usuario
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    // Asignar los valores a variables
    $imagen = $user['foto'];
    $nombre = $user['nombre_completo'];
    $cedula = $user['cedula'];
    $cargo = $user['roles'];
    $correo = $user['email'];
} else {
    echo "No se encontraron datos para este usuario.";
}
// Cerrar la consulta
$stmt->close();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>.::InduAPP::.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../css/images/logo.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css?v=1.1" type="text/css">
</head>
<nav class="topbar">
    <img src="../css/images/logo.png" class="logo"></img>
    <div class="menu-container">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="../Vista/bienvenido.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item has-submenu">
                <a href="#">Produccion</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="../Vista/entradas_produccion.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-up mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Entradas producción</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/consumo_produccion.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Consumo producción</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Soporte</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item has-submenu">
                <a href="#">Ti</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="../Vista/agregar_inventario.php" target="view" width="100%" height="100%" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-up mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Agregar Inventario</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/ver_inventario.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Inventario Activo</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/consumo_produccion.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Inventario Bajas</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/consumo_produccion.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">SimCard</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item has-submenu">
                <a href="#">Vigilancia</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="../Vista/agregar_inventario.php" target="view" width="100%" height="100%" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-up mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Agregar Inventario</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/ver_inventario.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Inventario Activo</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/consumo_produccion.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">Inventario Bajas</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../Vista/consumo_produccion.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center"><span
                class="fa-solid fa-solid fa-arrow-down mr-3"></span><span class="menu-text">SimCard</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="../Vista/ver_ticket.php" target="view" class="d-flex align-items-center">Tickets</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="btn config"><img src="../css/images/confi.png" height="35px"></button>
    <div class="user-profile">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $imagen; ?>" class="img-perfil" alt="Foto de perfil">
        <div class="user-dropdown">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $imagen; ?>" alt="Imagen de perfil" >            
        <h3><?php echo $nombre_completo; ?></h3>
            <p><strong>Usuario:</strong> <?php echo $usuario; ?></p>
            <p><strong>Usuario Softland:</strong> <?php echo $usuario_soft; ?></p>
            <p><strong>Cargo:</strong> <?php echo $cargo; ?></p>
            <p><strong>Correo:</strong> <?php echo $correo; ?></p>
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.open('../Vista/editar_perfil.php', 'view');">Editar Perfil</button>
            <form action="../Controlador/logout.php" method="POST">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar Sesion</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>

<div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-4 pt-5">
      <iframe src="../Vista/bienvenido.php" name="view" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>document.querySelector('.menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('active');
});
</script>
<?php include('../Vista/chat.php'); ?>
  <footer class="footer mt-auto">
    <p>&copy; Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
    <p></p>
  </footer>
  <?php include('opciones.php'); ?>

</body>

</html>


En el primer código, entre estas 2 tablas ... u.*, r.* ... (usuarios y roles) ¿tienen todas las columnas nombres diferentes? Si hay algún conflicto, evita usar *. Verifica con un var_dump($_SESSION); en ambos scripts a ver si es correcta la estructura y los datos que necesitas.
